# Soft question about manipulating complex inequalities

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question

I am sometimes surprised by how adept people are at manipulating inequalities involving absolute values of complex numbers.

I know that by representing z in rectangular coordinates, it is relatively straightforward to show that  $\mid \frac{1}{z} -1 \mid = \frac{1}{2}$ is the circle $\mid z- \frac{4}{3} \mid = \frac{2}{3}$ (using basic properties of the transformation $w= \frac{1}{z}$ also works I believe).  What I don't have a good intuition for is whether or not the former expression can be algebraically manipulated into the latter expression by staying in the variable z (i.e., not switching to rectangular or polar coordinates).  After playing around with this for a little, my guess is that this is not possible.  What I am wondering is: are there any general rules that I could apply at the beginning to tell me whether or not such a manipulation is possible.

Comment: I've removed the "logic" tag, which is for questions about the *specific subfield* [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic), not questions about mathematical reasoning in general.

Comment: I agree this is more about general reasoning.  A possible reason for keeping the "logic" tag: any systemic approach to these types of questions would surely involve formal logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition can be rewritten as:

$$
0 = \left| \frac{1}{z} -1 \right|^2 - \frac{1}{4}= \frac{(1-z)(1-\bar z)}{|z|^2} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{4 - 4 z - 4 \bar z+4|z|^2 - |z|^2}{4 |z|^2}
$$

It follows that the numerator must be $0\,$, so:

$$
0 = 4 - 4 z - 4 \bar z+3|z|^2 = \frac{1}{3}\Big((3z-4)(3 \bar z -4) - 4\Big) = \frac{1}{3}\Big(|3z-4|^2 - 4\Big)
$$

The latter gives $\displaystyle|3z-4|=2 \iff \left|z - \frac{4}{3}\right| = \frac{2}{3}\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  The technique is applicable in many cases of such transformations. The key points are:

- $\;|z|^2 = z \bar z\,$, which allows expanding the modulus in terms of conjugates;
- recognizing that $|z|^2 + \bar a z + a \bar z = (z+a)(\bar z + \bar a) - |a|^2 = |z+a|^2 - |a|^2\,$, which allows collecting such expressions back into a modulus form.

Comment: I waited before looking at your answer to see if I could figure it.  I couldn't.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd Here are some more problems among the recently posted, where you could practice similar ideas to solve without resorting to Cartesian - [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320258/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308080/), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305936/), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303277/), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296382/), [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293825/).

Comment: Thanks, I solved those problems.  I think my issue was that I was stubbornly trying to only use algebraic manipulations.  The way I see it, your key step of noticing that you could just look at the numerator was not a purely algebraic step: it required some reasoning that was extra-algebraic.  In this sense, I think I was originally correct in saying that such a manipulation is impossible.  (This is why I kept bringing up logic; how does one define a purely algebraic move?)  Nevertheless I didn't try your approach and I am happy you showed it to me.